# On the growth of sample paths of Gaussian random fields

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, random-functions

Consider a centered Gaussian random field on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with continuous covariance and a.s. continuous sample paths. What is known about the growth of the sample paths at infinity of such a random field?

1. If the random field is assumed in addition to be stationary, it appears, based on the exponential decay of the tail probabilities, that the growth should be logarithmic (as it is in the one-dimensional case) but is that written up somewhere? (The one-dimensional case is treated in Theorem 1.4. in this article: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2239990).
2. Without assuming stationarity, I'm interested if the following is true: Given that the covariance has polynomial growth, is it true that sample paths have a.s. polynomial growth?

Comment: Do you mean stationary field?

Comment: There are results like by Colella and Lanford. See for example this paper by Rosen and Simon which mention almost sure $\sqrt{\log|x|}$ type growth https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-42/issue-1/Global-support-properties-of-stationary-ergodic-processes/10.1215/S0012-7094-75-04203-9.short

Comment: @oferzeitouni, I suppose to get logarithmic growth, the field should be stationary or close to stationary. But I'm more interested in this: Given that the covariance has polynomial growth, is it true that sample paths have a.s. polynomial growth?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, thanks for the references, these do address sample path growth but the context seems to be rather different. I'm more interested in multi-dimensional version of a result like Theorem 1.4 in this article: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2239990

Comment: Maybe the context is not familiar to you but it is not different. The papers I mentioned concern random distributions in $S'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ but if you mollify them by convolution then you get one of the stationary multidmensional Gaussian processes you are considering. Namely your $X(t), t\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is $q(f(\cdot-t))$ in the notations of Rosen and Simon. Also note their result is sharper than the upper bound in Thm 1.4 of Marcus.

Comment: @S.Z.  Can you clarify the question by making the implicit conditions that you are assuming, explicit?  Obviously standard Brownian motion satisfies  your assumptions as stated but not the conclusion. If you are assuming stationarity, that should be in the question, while if you are just after polynomial growth, that should be stated.

Comment: @YuvalPeres, I edited the question, hopefully it's clearer now. But I'm not sure what you mean by saying that the Brownian motion does not satisfy the "conclusion"? The sample paths of the Brownian motion are a.s. of logarithmic growth, as it follows, for example, from the theorem that I'm citing in the question.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, thank you for the clarification. But would such an argument work for a non-stationary Gaussian field with covariance of polynomial growth at infinity?

Comment: @S.Z. The paper you quote assumes stationarity. For Brownian motion, the growth of the paths is typically $t^{1/2}$ and the extrema are governed by the LIL., see e.g. the last line of https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/lecture-14-the-law-of-iterated-logarithm/

Comment: @YuvalPeres, thank you. Sorry, I got this confused with stationary increments... But still in case of the Brownian motion the sample paths grow not faster than the covariance, so could this be a general phenomenon?

Answer (score 1):

I will consider stationary
Gaussian processes $X_v$ indexed by $v\in Z^d$, not continuous time (the
argument for continuous time requires a bit of extra work, and some assumptions
on the short-time behavior of the covariance; smoothness of the covariance at $0$ should be enough). In general, good references on such questions are the lecture notes of R. Adler, or his book with Taylor.

By the [Royen Gaussian correlation inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_correlation_inequality)
$$ P(\sup_{v\in Z^d: |v|_\infty<T} |X_v|<R)\geq \prod_{v\in Z^d:|v|_\infty<T} P(|X_v|<R)=  \big(P(|X_0|<R)\big)^{(2T)^d}$$
from which you get a logarithmic behavior (that is, if $R> C_d \sqrt{\log T}$
then the probability above goes to $1$, with explicit $C_d$). The same bound can also be obtained from a union bound. A complimentary lower bound requires more work but with fast enough (any polynomial) decay of correlation, also holds.

A similar argument works for non-stationary fields, but of course the answer depends on the rate of growth of the covariance (and the move from discrete to continuous requires a bit more assumptions). In general, up to extra log factors, the growth of the variance (not covariance, as soon as the latter
decays fast enough, e.g. polynomially) determine the behavior.